# How to efficiently build and store semantic graph?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, algorithm, semantics

Surfing the net I ran into [Aquabrowser](http://www.serialssolutions.com/aquabrowser/) (no need to click, I'll post a pic of the relevant part).

It has a nice way of presenting search results and discovering semantically linked entities.

Here is a screenshot taken from [one](http://aqua.santacruzpl.org/) of the [demos](http://www.serialssolutions.com/aquabrowser-demos/).

On the left side you have they word you typed and related words.
Clicking them refines your results.

[image: aqua]

Now as an example project I have a data set of film entities and subjects (like wolrd-war-2 or prison-escape) and their relations.

Now I imagine several use cases, first where a user starts with a keyword.
For example "world war 2".

Then i would somehow like to calculate related keywords and rank them.

I think about some sql query like this:

Lets assume "world war 2" has id 3.

```
select keywordId, count(keywordId) as total from keywordRelations 
WHERE movieId IN (select movieId from keywordRelations 
                  join movies using (movieId)      
                  where keywordId=3) 
 group by keywordId order by total desc
```

which basically should select all movies which also have the keyword world-war-2 and then looks up the keywords which theese films have as well and selects those which occour the most.

I think with theese keywords I can select movies which match best and have a nice tag cloud containing similar movies and related keywords.

I think this should work but its very, very, very inefficient.

And its also only one level or relation.

There must be a better way to do this, but how??

I basically have an collection of entities. They could be different entities (movies, actors, subjects, plot-keywords) etc.

I also have relations between them.

It must somehow be possible to efficiently calculate "semantic distance" for entities.

I also would like to implement more levels of relation.

But I am totally stuck. Well I have tried different approaches but everything ends up in some algorithms that take ages to calculate and the runtime grows exponentially.

Are there any database systems available optimized for that?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want an [RDF triplestore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore).  [Redland](http://librdf.org/) is a pretty commonly used one, but it really depends on your needs.  Queries are done in [SPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL), not SQL.  Also... you have to drink the semantic web koolaid.

Comment: very nice +1. looks like what i was looking for. great resources

Comment: +1 just for the koolaid comment though have to admit I have long since been addicted to it!

Answer (score 1):

From your tags I see you're more familiar with sql, and I think it's still possible to use it effectively for your task.

I have an application where a custom-made full-text search implemented using sqlite as a database. In the search field I can enter terms and popup list will show suggestions about the word and for any next word only those are shown that appears in the articles where previously entered words appeared. So it's similar to the task you described

To make things more simple let's assume we have only three tables. I suppose you have a different schema and even details can be different but my explanation is just to give an idea.

- Words 
  [Id, Word]  The table contains words (keywords)
- Index 
  [Id, WordId, ArticleId]
  This table (indexed also by WordId) lists articles where this term appeared
- ArticleRanges 
  [ArticleId, IndexIdFrom, IndexIdTo]
  This table lists ranges of Index.Id for any given Article (obviously also indexed by ArticleId) . This table requires that for any new or updated article Index table should contain entries having known from-to range. I suppose it can be achieved with any RDBMS with a little help of autoincrement feature

So for any given string of words you

- Intersect all articles where all previous words appeared. This will narrow the search. SELECT ArticleId FROM Index Where WordId=... INTERSECT ...
- For the list of articles you can get ranges of records from ArticleRanges table
- For this range you can effectively query WordId lists from Index grouping the results to get Count and finally sort by it.

Although I listed them as separate actions, the final query can be just big sql based on the parsed query string.

Comment: great idea, gotta walk it thorugh once more but i get the principle!